# VS17 Team Explorer Project drop down section disappears when installing vsix extension with team explorer plugin

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, team-explorer

I have an extension that add custom project type and some additional Team Explorer plugin, that should be shown under the project drop-down list in Team Explorer.

It works fine in VS15, however if I migrate the project to VS17, and generate the new vsix, when I install it, the project drop-down disappears.

The other parts of the extension are working well, so I can create custom project type.

```
[VS17 with extension] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tua7v.jpg
[VS17 without extension] https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqDhY.jpg
[VS15 with extension] https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDRPM.jpg
[vsix manifest file] https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMLw7.jpg
```

The custom tabs shown in VS15 should appear also in VS17.
How can I make the custom plugins visible in Team Explorer?

Comment: When you generate a new vsix, are you recompiling the extension against VS 2017 binaries?  For historical reasons, the Team Explorer interfaces (ex: ITeamExplorerPage, etc) are versioned with each major version of VS.  A recompile is needed on major version boundaries.

Comment: Hi Chad, What I have done is migrated the solution from VS15 to VS17. Then updated the vsixmanifest and rebuilt the solution in debug mode. This generated a vsix file that I installed. Then the project drop down list disappeared and the plugins did not show up. I also tried with this sample project, and got the same result: https://hamidshahid.blogspot.com/2017/09/extending-team-explorer-in-vs2017.html